# Stop style HOVER behaviour with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with style.

This style

```
 body .d:hover
    {
      background-color:red;
    }
```

But I want (if possible) that Jquery will stop this hover behaviour.

I tried with

```
 $(".d").hover(function () { return false;});
 $(".d").mouseenter(function () { return false;});
```

nothing helped.

any help ?

**here is the [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/akunew/31/edit)** ( I want that after pressing the button - nothing will happen when hovering.)

Comment: I assume removing the style declaration is not possible?

Comment: yeah it is not possible. thanks Felix. ( and i would like a jquery solution rather then applying another style with !important  ...:-)

Comment: if d:hover have a single line on style, why just dont change the class name?

Comment: You can't disable CSS behaviour. I would use 2 classes as suggested here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069110/remove-hover-css-behavior-from-element

Comment: @Ark this is a stupid sample. I want to know if I can **prevent hover behaviour with jquery**.

Comment: You might need to do something like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754546/can-i-disable-a-css-hover-effect-via-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop this behavior constantly, you may remove the stylesheet rule, according to [W3C wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript):

```
function stop(m) {
    $.each(document.styleSheets, function(i, sheet) {
        $.each(sheet.rules, function(i, rule) {
            if (new RegExp(m + "\\s*:hover").test(rule.selectorText)) {
                sheet.deleteRule(i);
            }  // TODO: improve RegExp
        });
    });
}
stop(".d");
```

If you want to change the state without removing, there is an option to change `styleSheet.disabled` property, in case you have the `:hover` rule set in a separate stylesheet.

Note, that I'm not sure about the compatibility issues here, it should be determined additionally.

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/akunew/10/edit

Answer (score 1):

Add a new definition to your CSS:

```
.d.no-hover:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Now you can just add the `no-hover` class to the elements which should no longer have a hover effect:

```
$(obj).addClass('no-hover');
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this kind of trick: http://jsbin.com/akunew/14/edit

```
<div style="border:solid 1px red;height:100px;width:100px;" class="d"> </div>
<input  type="button" value="stop this hover" onclick="stop()" id="btn"/>
```

remove the class:

```
function stop(){
  $(".d").addClass('e').removeClass('d');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you calling `onclick="stop(this)"` it will get `input` as your `$(obj)`, not your element `.d`.

**EDIT** There is no javascript solution to remove `:hover`

Comment: Yes, but fixing this does not solve the problem... or did you try it?

Comment: oopsss my very bad. fixing

Answer (score 0):

based on ur JSBIN example. below code will work

function stop(obj) 
    {
      $(obj).hover(function () { 
        $(this).css('background-color','white');
        return false;});
      $(obj).mouseenter(function () { 
        $(this).css('background-color','white');
        return false;});

```
  $('body').append('<style>body div.d:hover {background-color:transparent !important}</style>');
}
```

u have overwrite :hover css of that particular element

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
.d:hover
{
    background-color:Red;
}
.noClass
{
    background-color:none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function stop()
{
    $(".d").addClass('noClass').removeClass('d');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick- when i am on hover onto an element (and click something inside that HOVERed element), then you can use this javascript method to cancel that hover css:

```
document.getElementById('sarchevi').className='active';
//on mouse move, remove class
(function(){
    var moved = false
    window.onmousemove = function(e)
    { if(!moved){ moved = true;  document.getElementById('sarchevi').className ='a'; } }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is four years old, but future visitors should know about the modern approach to this particular problem.

---

You can use a simple solution that (at its core) uses a CSS property and is supported by all browsers except IE < 11.

```
$('.d').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

You might as well just copy this specific class from Bootstrap:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

And then apply it via jQuery:

```
$('.d').addClass('disabled');
```

Keep in mind, however, that this CSS property prevents the element from capturing any DOM events (such as *hover*, but also *click*, etc.)