# javascript toggle button with css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this toggle button in which when i click on it the button shows that it is active and the css changes so it is darker. but when i click the other button the toggle doesn't deactivate (on/off) i want to change that so that it turns on when i click on it and off when i click on the other button.

**buttons**

```
<div class="btn-group float_right">
    <a id="gridBtn" onclick="$.views.stuff.ToggleView('gridView')" title="View as grid" class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-th-large"></i></a>
    <a id="listBtn" onclick="$.views.stuff.ToggleView('listView')" title="View as list" class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-th-list"></i></a>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('a#gridBtn').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("down");
        });
        $('a#listBtn').click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("down");
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you show some problem in Jsfiddler

Comment: One advice is to remove the onlick from your html and put them in the $("...).click part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your `#gridBtn` the `down` class by using:

```
$('#gridBtn').addClass('down');
```

Also, there's no need for two separate click handlers:

```
  $('a#gridBtn, a#listBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('down').siblings().removeClass('down');
  });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/54xfN/3/)

Comment: is there a way to remove the hover feature from a button that has `.addClass('down')` to it?

Comment: It'd be better to do that using CSS, [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069110/remove-hover-css-behavior-from-element) should be able to help

Answer (score 3):

Try this CSS trick:

```
<div class="btn-group float_right">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="viewbuttons" />
        <a id="gridBtn" .....>...</a>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="viewbuttons" />
        <a id="listBtn" .....>...</a>
    </label>
</div>
```

Then add this CSS:

```
.btn-group input {display:none}
.btn-group a { /* your "deselected" styles here */ }
.btn-group input+a { /* your "selected" styles here */ }
```

This is extremely efficient since you don't need any jQuery to make it work ;)

Comment: very handy i will give it a try and see how it works. Thanks for trick.

Comment: If you're not bothered about the semantics of your HTML that is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the state of the other button at the same time?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#gridBtn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("down");
        $('a#listBtn').attr('class', 'up');
    });
    $('a#listBtn').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("down");
        $('a#gridBtn').attr('class', 'up');
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked great with what i have. Is there a way to have `a#gridBtn` toggleClass down by default on page load because that is how it is displayed

Comment: <a id="gridBtn" title="View as grid" class="btn down" href="#"> this will be changed by jquery when the click event happens