# Remove menu hover action after clicking the menu in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dropdown menu that works by `Classic CSS hover`

if you've opened the menu with a `click event`, i need the hover effect to be removed but i can't because you're still hovering over the menu the menu doesn't `disappear` until you `hover off` which isn't ideal. I also tried using `.hide()` but then that messes with CSS hover functionality.

Is there a way in jQuery to remove the CSS hover activation of an element?

```
 $("ul.nav > li").click(function(e) {
   var url = $(this).attr("url");
   $(this).css('background', '#bbb');
   if( url == 'logoutServlet') {
       $.get('logoutServlet');
       window.location = "/a";
   }else{
       $("#content").html('Loading...').load(url);
  }       
});
```

Comment: You cannot remove hover effect. Add a new class and add empty to its hover css. This quesion has an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5069151/3639582

Comment: are u having a class name hover??

Comment: @ Don No i actually used classic hover method to show submenu on hover

Answer (score 0):

Hover state is not a class, you should use CSS to change hover behavior of an element.

for example:

```
a.whatever { color: black; } /* Default state */
a.whatever:hover { text-decoration: none; color: black; } /* Hover state */
```

You can match hover state rules with other states behavior to make it look the same.