# How to remove all hovers on small devices?

Tags: html, css

How to remove hover effects for elements in css.

I have for example such html and css:

```css
@media (max-width: 1220px) {
  .column {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .para {
    display: none;
  }
  .link:hover {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .column {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <a class="link" href="#">Some link</a>
  <p class="para">
    Some para
  </p>
</div>
```

By fact there is much more element. How to disable all hover for elements for screen size less than 992px?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxv339vh/)

Comment: combine your css media query with this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069110/remove-hover-css-behavior-from-element

Comment: both the accepted answer to that post and the one with 124 votes would work nicely

Comment: @YvonneAburrow doesn't work for me. in example case it is different elements, in my case it is the same elemtn in different media size

Comment: I think yvonnes answer is great, instead of `removing on smaller devices` do: `add hover on big devices` in css its always easier to add then to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @media (max-width: 1220px) {
  .column {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .para {
    display: none;
  }

}

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1220px) and (min-width: 993px) {

      .link:hover {
        color: red;
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: 992px) {
      .column {
        width: 100px;
      }

    }
```

What is happening in your original CSS is that because the first media query is for `max-width: 1220px`, that also applies to the second media query. Therefore, you need to specify a `min-width` in the first query, so that the `:hover` condition is not applied to all screens with `max-width: 1220px` (which would include screens with `max-width 992px` as well).

**EDITED** to reflect the requirement that some styles DO apply to all screen resolutions below 1220px.

Comment: the issue is that i need some classes to be used in max-width: 992px, for example leave .para display: block. note that it is just example, by fact it is more that 20 classes with 100 elements

Comment: well, you can have one media query that encompasses all screen resolutions, as in your OP, and another that specifies that hover states only happen between the two screen resolutions (as in my answer).

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer :)  (yay, finally broken the 200 barrier, made my day)