# Remove 'body a:hover' CSS behavior from element

Tags: css

This question was asked before, but with slightly different cases. In my case, I have `body a:hover` style defined and I want to disable it for some elements. According to a suggested answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069110/remove-hover-css-behavior-from-element) I have tried:

CSS:

```
body:not(.nohover a) a:hover {  
    color: #006699;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="nohover">
   <a href="mylink.html">My link text</a>
</div>
```

But it did not work. Does anyone know if it can be done with the `:not` pseudo-class? Or in a different way?

**Edit:** I think dippas was not wearing his reading glasses when marking this question as a duplicate; even stronger as an "exact duplicate". Fortunately, people like Edmund Reed tried to be helpful instead, and helped me answering my question.

Comment: have you add class `nohover` in your `<a>` element in which you want to disable?
`<a class="nohover">blah</a>`

Comment: Yes. I have added it to my question above.

Comment: `body:not(.nohover a) a:hover` should be `body a:not(.nohover):hover`, and apply the class to the `a` itself, not a surrounding div.

Comment: @Edmund Reed: your answer proves to be working! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
body:not(.nohover)>a:hover { 
 color: #006699;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a>hover</a>
  <a>hover</a>     
  <div class="nohover">
    <a>no hover</a>
  </div>  
</body>
```

the css only applied if the structure is like `body > a` or will not work on structure `body > .nohover > a`.
and this css also will not applied if the structure did not meet `body > a`, thus if you try to applied this css to element with structure `body > element > a` this css wont work