# Disable hover on mobile and tablet devices

Tags: css, svg, sass, hover, media-queries

How to disable hover in mobile and tablet devices? The img tag is an SVG file.

*scss file:*

```
.menu-link:hover {
    img { filter: invert(40%) sepia(90%) saturate(2460%) hue-rotate(204deg) brightness(93%) contrast(93%); }
    .sidebar-text-menu { 
        font-weight: bold;
        color:$blue; 
        opacity: 1;
    }
    i{
           filter: invert(40%) sepia(90%) saturate(2460%) hue-rotate(204deg) brightness(93%) contrast(93%);
    }
}
```

Comment: May be this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754497/css-disable-hover-effect/26755719, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069110/remove-hover-css-behavior-from-element.  just set these solution in media qurie `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove/ignore :hover css style on touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885255/how-to-remove-ignore-hover-css-style-on-touch-devices)

Answer (score 4):

There's pretty good browser support for the `@media` queries [hover](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_at-rules_media_hover) and [pointer](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_at-rules_media_pointer). You can use those in a combination to get the effect you are looking for:

```css
@media(hover: hover) and (pointer: fine) {
    .menu-link:hover {
        /* Targeting devices with mouse cursor and :hover */
    }
}
```

Targeting devices based on `width` will most likely include some mobile devices, which is not what you want in this case.

Comment: Great answer Cody! Alternatively, if like me you code desktop first and often find you need to revert or change some styles for mobile when hover is not available - I do a `@media only screen and (hover: none) and (pointer: coarse) { }`. The `only screen` is not essential here I just add it as good practice.